# x64 calls to function in another dll

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, assembly, 64-bit

Can someone explain to me the following behavior on x64 platform: 
If I call from my executable to a function in another dll in x64 the disassembled code looks something like this:

```
000000014000149E FF 15 34 CF 00 00  call  qword ptr [__imp_CFuncInDll (14000E3D8h)]
```

I realize that the debugger calculates the relative address to this absolute address 14000E3C0h. However unlike x86 code if I'll disassemble the address 14000E3D8h it looks like garbage:

```
__imp_CFuncInDll:
000000014000E3D8 19 10                sbb         dword ptr [rax],edx  
000000014000E3DA 25 FC FE 07 00       and         eax,7FEFCh  
000000014000E3DF 00 14 10             add         byte ptr [rax+rdx],dl  
000000014000E3E2 25 FC FE 07 00       and         eax,7FEFCh  
000000014000E3E7 00 00                add         byte ptr [rax],al  
.......
```

When I step into the call I can see that instead of getting into the garbage address the code jumps to a valid address:

```
000007FEFC251019 E9 62 00 00 00       jmp         CFuncInDll (7FEFC251080h)
```

My question:
How the call instruction is decoded on x64 when the target is in another module?
In x86 the call target of this code:

```
FF 15 34 CF 00 00    call
```

was: target = next instruction address + 0x0000CF34
While on x64 it looks like this is not the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`call  qword ptr [__imp_CFuncInDll (14000E3D8h)]` is an indirect call through a pointer. The pointer's address is 0x14000E3D8.  If you look at the code bytes of your non-sense disassembly, they turn out to contain the following:

```
19 10 25 FC FE 07 00 00
```

Which is a little-endian quadword is: `000007fe.fc251019` - the address of the `jmp CFuncInDll` instruction you get to when you single step.

Basically, the call to an import function is being assembled as a call through an entry in a table of addresses to a small 'thunk' that jumps to the actual function implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to disassemble a pointer to the code instead of the code.

This instruction

`000000014000149E FF 15 34 CF 00 00  call  qword ptr [__imp_CFuncInDll (14000E3D8h)]`

reads a pointer from the address that is relative to the beginning of the instruction following it, that is, it adds 14000149EH, 6 (length of this `call` instruction) and 0CF34H, arrives at address 14000E3D8H, reads 8 bytes from there, and that (those 8 bytes: 19H, 10H, 25H, 0FCH, 0FEH, 7H, 0, 0) is the address 7FEFC251019H where this `call` transfers control.

You should be disassemblying at address 7FEFC251019H.